# Jenkins CI timings erratic

Tags: python, jenkins, junit, timing

I recently moved my Jenkins CI setup to a new computer. Everything works fine, apart from the fact the build timings are erratic to say the least. For example note timing discrepancy here:

[Jenkins test result with inconsistent timings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeACC.png)

Sometimes, the timing sitution seems to improve / change when re-starting the server.

I am running Jenkins 2.89.2 on Win10. Moreover, I have not seen other people complain about this issue - might not be a bug, but an issue with my configuration...

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Update: following some digging through the underlying JUnit xml reports, and looking at my old setup, it seems that the issue has in fact been around for a while, and relates (I now believe) only to the folder-in-build, multi-module view.

Comment: The 30 minutes value should come from the junit xml report file (or whatever report format you're using), which is then rendered by jenkins, so I'd start by looking at the report file in your job's workspace. Do you use junit publisher or some other plugin?

Comment: @hoefling Thanks for the hint. So the junit xml contains the timings for the individual tests that add up to the 0.98s indicated top right in the screenshot, but the only place the 30min features in the xml is as the duration of the whole build (containing multiple modules) - for some reason this is apparently being read as the duration of the module's tests, giving rise to the other timing value shown...

Comment: Try to reproduce this issue in your local repo - will the generated xml report have wrong cumulated duration? If yes, this is not a jenkins issue, but rather an issue with your test suite or even a junit bug. You could then update your question to attract the right people that can help you.

Comment: @hoefling Did some more digging: there is nothing wrong with the timings in the xml report, what is wrong is how cumulative times are extracted - specifically for the folder-in-build, multi-module view. I have now looked at various JUnit plug-in / Jenkins version combinations and seen the issue throughout.